# java.lang.NullPointerException at serviceimpl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, primefaces

im new to this java. I facing a problem to load the data from database. I have create the service & dao & hibernate. But i facing the following problem. I have tried keep changing the code but doesn't work.

Need some help here.
**Error when load the page**

```
Jul 09, 2014 5:47:53 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/secured/Letters/SalesLetter.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean LetterBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.faces.expression.ELDelegatingVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ELDelegatingVariableResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveOriginal(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver.resolveVariable(SpringBeanVariableResolver.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:53)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:143)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:46)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vipro.service.LetterServiceImpl.findAll(LetterServiceImpl.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy52.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.vipro.utils.spring.CodeUtil.getLetterAsItems(CodeUtil.java:164)
    at com.vipro.jsf.bean.letters.LetterBean.init(LetterBean.java:46)
    ... 117 more

Jul 09, 2014 5:47:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/vipro] threw exception [An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean LetterBean] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vipro.service.LetterServiceImpl.findAll(LetterServiceImpl.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy52.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.vipro.utils.spring.CodeUtil.getLetterAsItems(CodeUtil.java:164)
    at com.vipro.jsf.bean.letters.LetterBean.init(LetterBean.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.faces.expression.ELDelegatingVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ELDelegatingVariableResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveOriginal(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.jsf.SpringBeanVariableResolver.resolveVariable(SpringBeanVariableResolver.java:47)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:53)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:143)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:46)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:44)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:55)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Letter html

```
<p:column style="width:20%;text-align:left" id="Typeofletter">
                    <h:outputText value="Types of letter"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width:20%;text-align:left">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="projectList" value="#{LetterBean.listLetter}" 
                         required="true" style="width:200px" for="Types of Letter">  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{LetterBean.listLetter}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
```

LetterBean

```
package com.vipro.jsf.bean.letters;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import com.vipro.dto.ProgressiveBillingUnitSeachDTO;
import com.vipro.service.ProjectService;
import com.vipro.utils.spring.CodeUtil;

public class LetterBean {

    private List<SelectItem> listProject = null;
    private List<SelectItem> listLetter = null;

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {
        listProject = CodeUtil.getProjectAsItems();
        listLetter = CodeUtil.getLetterAsItems();
    }
```

LetterService.java

```
package com.vipro.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.vipro.data.Letter;
import com.vipro.data.Project;

public interface LetterService {

    public void insert(Letter c);

    public void update(Letter c);

    public List<Letter> findAll();

}
```

LetterserviceImpl.java

```
package com.vipro.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.vipro.dao.LetterDao;
import com.vipro.data.Letter;


@Service("com.vipro.service.LetterService")
public class LetterServiceImpl implements LetterService {

    private LetterDao letterDao;

    @Override
    public void insert(Letter c) {
        letterDao.insert(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Letter c) {
        letterDao.update(c);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Letter> findAll() {
        return letterDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

LetterDao.java

```
package com.vipro.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.vipro.common.Dao;
import com.vipro.data.Letter;

public interface LetterDao extends Dao<Letter> {

    //public List<Letter> findAllAvailLetter();findAvailLetter
    public List<Letter> findAll();
    //public List<Letter> findByProjectId(Long projectId);
    }
```

LetterDaoImpl.java

```
package com.vipro.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.vipro.common.DaoImpl;
import com.vipro.data.Letter;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Repository("com.vipro.dao.LetterDao")
public class LetterDaoImpl extends DaoImpl<Letter> implements LetterDao {

    @Override
    public List<Letter> findAll() {
        String query = "select o from Letter o ";
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
    }

}
```

Comment: check line 27 of LetterServiceImpl. there it throws a NullPointerException. my guess: letterDao is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your service class. You have missed to add autowire at DAO class declarations 
Please add the following at service class and try

```
@Autowired
private LetterDao letterDao;
```

Comment: why @Autowired must be added?

Comment: In simple term it is used to Assigning required object at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In `LetterServiceImpl`, need to inject letterDao as it is `null`

```
@Autowired
private LetterDao letterDao;
```